# Django ForeignKey.on_delete replace deleted object with a constant

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Scenario:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class B(models.Model):
    ref_to_A = models.ForeignKey(A, on_delete=models.CASCADE) <--- this part here
```

Above scenario presents two models: A and B.
B has a filed with reference to A instance.
What I want is, on deleting this referenced instance of model A- to replace `ref_to_A` with it's `name` field. So that after deleting object field B.ref_to_A == A.name.

None of the functions for on_delete (CASCADE/SET_NULL/SET_DEFAULT) seems like good starting point except `models.SET()` (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey) which I don't understand from `Django's` docs example. This could be it, but can't think of a way to pass to this `models.SET()` function which will return a `self.name` from related object of `model A`.

Another approach I've encountered searching for solution is to user `signals`, but after some research I can't really grasp how to start with this.

This is important to me, because after deleting objects in db, I have to keep track to at least one specific field of related object.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case you can only replace `ref_to_A` with another foreign key of `A`, not arbitrary data like name which is a string.

Comment: You might want to add another field for this purpose, like `old_A_name` that is a `CharField`. Then you can add a `post_delete` signal for `A`, that updates all references to an `A` instance in the `B` model to update `old_A_name`

Comment: @bdbd thanks. Now I get that in `Django's` example they replace deleted reference with this specific object `username='deleted'`.